# Animate floating DIVs repositioning as other floating DIVs are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a series of floating DIVs which may be hidden (display:none) when clicked by the user. When one is hidden, the other DIVs "jump" to fill it's place (as they are also floating).

However, I would like them to smoothly "slide" into their new position. What is the best way to do this? I have included a sample page below - if you dump it into any editor it is fully functional except for the feature I am trying to add (the animation).

```js
function hideBox(num) {
  document.getElementById('box' + num).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 63px;
  background-color: #52c6ec;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 37px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1" onclick="hideBox(1)">Box 1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2" onclick="hideBox(2)">Box 2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3" onclick="hideBox(3)">Box 3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4" onclick="hideBox(4)">Box 4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5" onclick="hideBox(5)">Box 5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6" onclick="hideBox(6)">Box 6</div>
<div class="box" id="box7" onclick="hideBox(7)">Box 7</div>
<div class="box" id="box8" onclick="hideBox(8)">Box 8</div>
<div class="box" id="box9" onclick="hideBox(9)">Box 9</div>
<div class="box" id="box10" onclick="hideBox(10)">Box 10</div>
<div class="box" id="box11" onclick="hideBox(11)">Box 11</div>
<div class="box" id="box12" onclick="hideBox(12)">Box 12</div>
<div class="box" id="box13" onclick="hideBox(13)">Box 13</div>
<div class="box" id="box14" onclick="hideBox(14)">Box 14</div>
<div class="box" id="box15" onclick="hideBox(15)">Box 15</div>
<div class="box" id="box16" onclick="hideBox(16)">Box 16</div>
<div class="box" id="box17" onclick="hideBox(17)">Box 17</div>
<div class="box" id="box18" onclick="hideBox(18)">Box 18</div>
<div class="box" id="box19" onclick="hideBox(19)">Box 19</div>
<div class="box" id="box20" onclick="hideBox(20)">Box 20</div>
<div class="box" id="box21" onclick="hideBox(21)">Box 21</div>
<div class="box" id="box22" onclick="hideBox(22)">Box 22</div>
<div class="box" id="box23" onclick="hideBox(23)">Box 23</div>
<div class="box" id="box24" onclick="hideBox(24)">Box 24</div>
<div class="box" id="box25" onclick="hideBox(25)">Box 25</div>
<div class="box" id="box26" onclick="hideBox(26)">Box 26</div>
<div class="box" id="box27" onclick="hideBox(27)">Box 27</div>
<div class="box" id="box28" onclick="hideBox(28)">Box 28</div>
<div class="box" id="box29" onclick="hideBox(29)">Box 29</div>
<div class="box" id="box30" onclick="hideBox(30)">Box 30</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a more animated version where the boxes actually animate the changing of rows, this would also do it: http://jsfiddle.net/rCgxD/1/. This one uses jQuery as well for its robust libraries and animations. The following is the javascript code I used:

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').click(function(){
       var boxpositions = [];
        $('.box').not(this).each(function(index,elem){
           boxpositions[index] = [$(elem).position().top,$(elem).position().left];
        });
        var thisposition = [$(this).position().top,$(this).position().left];
       $(this).hide();
        var newpositions = [];
        $('.box').not(this).each(function(index,elem){
           newpositions[index] = [$(elem).position().top,$(elem).position().left];
        });
        $(this).show().css({position:'absolute',top:thisposition[0],left:thisposition[1]}).hide(200);
        $('.box').not(this).each(function(tindex,telem){
            $(telem).css({position:'absolute',top:boxpositions[tindex][0],left:boxpositions[tindex][1]}).animate({top:newpositions[tindex][0],left:newpositions[tindex][1]},200,function(){$(this).css({position:'static',top:'auto',left:'auto'});});;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is exactly what I had in mind! Let me try it out myself - I wil let you know how it goes!

Comment: I am having an issue implementing this - the DIVs in the actual code I am using are slightly more complex than the ones in my example (for simplicity's sake).

The DIVs I have are `float:left` and `position:relative`, but they have a smaller DIV within them that is `position:absolute` in order to get the positioning right. When I drop in your code I am able to recreate this effect _once_ with all of the DIVs sliding over and then the inner DIVs get misaligned. Any idea how I could work around this to use your code? Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Would you happen to have an example in which I can view?

Comment: Well, this is very strange. I attempted to recreate my exact code in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rCgxD/2/) and it works. However, my PHP appears to generate the same exact code on my local test environment and the inner boxes start rendering at the bottom of the screen. However, `absolute` positioning was the only way I could get them to appear in the right place to begin with. Do you know why I may be having this issue, or if there is a way I can modify the code you provided to allow for this? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Check for other css/factors interfering with the boxes with Developer Tools/Firebug/Element Inspector. It is possible that a framework or such is messing things up

Comment: In this little experiment I am not using anything besides jQuery that I have not written myself - perhaps that is the problem! :) After playing with this in jsFiddle for quite some time I am unable to recreate the issue I am experiencing in my code, so it sounds like I need to take some time and sort it out. Thank you again for your excellent answer and all of your help!

Comment: I have found it!!! The issue in my code seems to be that the function you provided above sets the position of the container DIV to "static". Removing this property in Chrome Inspector fixes the issue with the inner DIV being misaligned, but breaks the scrolling effect! Do you have any advice for a workaround? Thank you again!

Comment: Also, is there possibly a way to make this into a function that I can call `onclick`? That way, I could choose when to invoke it (as some DIVs need to be hidden, while some need to stay). This is brand new territory for me but I will see if I can figure it out. I have learned a great deal from your code already!

Comment: FYI - it seems to work OK when I change that `static` in your code to `relative` but I am not sure I understand why. Please let me know if you think this would cause problems. Still trying to figure out how to make it a function I can call `onclick`!

Comment: position static is the default value for a `div` - since you changed it to something else in your site of course it won't work - I'm so sorry that I didn't think of that (How dumb of me). As for `onclick`, is this what you're looking for (with the `relative` fix)? http://jsfiddle.net/Qc38F/

Answer (score 2):

As you have `jQuery` in the tags, the simplest thing you can do is use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

You don't even need to add all those `onclick` handlers in your `HTML` code, simply use:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
 $(this).hide(200); //change width,height and opacity to 0 in 200miliseconds
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dZ9Dr/).

But, if you want a library-free solution, here is a quick recursive one:

```
function hideBox(num, perc) {
    if(perc == undefined)
        perc = 100;

    if(perc-- > 0)
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('box'+num).style.width = perc + 'px'; 
            hideBox(num,perc);
        }, 1);
    else
        document.getElementById('box'+num).style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dZ9Dr/1/)

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer - what an elegant solution. I like ksuperplane's script better because after the clicked DIV disappears, all of the other DIVs slide to their new locations rather than snapping. But this is a neat trick that I am sure I will use in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla Javascript this would be difficult (and extensive) but using jQuery as you have tagged it would be as simple as

```
$(".box").click(function()
{
   $(this).hide(400);
});
```

Where 400 is the number of milliseconds for which the animation runs.

Comment: How's this different from my answer already posted minutes ago? :)

Comment: Its not. I hadn't seen your answer when I started writing mine and running a JSFiddle to ensure it worked. Thus I upvoted your answer.